# "Save As" document link won't open, with error message ".. can't find .. correct location or web address"

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Document in a Template. Users input information and Save As a new genericized number. They then hit a button that auto populates an email to one of 5 people using Vlookup and based on the cost margin.

The file is Save As'd but the e-mail recipient cannot open the file, it reads invalid location. I can close and reopen the new renamed sheet and drag it into an e-mail. I need to link to the newly saved file's name that appears in the email.

```
Sub Email_created_Workbook()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Mess As Object, Recip
    Recip = [Sheet1!B28].Value & "; " & [Sheet1!B27].Value
    Dim strbody As String

    If ActiveWorkbook.Path <> "" Then
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        strbody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
                  "Hello,<br><br>" & _
                  "There is a New PO awaiting your approval :<br><B>" & _
                  ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</B> is created.<br>" & _
                   "Click on this link to open the file : " & _
                  "<A HREF=""file://" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & _
                  """>Link to Workbook</A>" & _
                  "<br><br>Regards," & _
                  "<br><br>Automated Approval System</font>"

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = Recip
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = ActiveWorkbook.Name
            .HTMLBody = strbody
            .Display   'or use .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "The ActiveWorkbook does not have a path, Save the file first."
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: 1]

The file name does adapt in my e-mail, from PO Template, but will not open.

[image: 2]

Comment: If the macro is in the workbook you need the path for, you should use `ThisWorkbook.FullName` and not `ActiveWorkbook.FullName`

Comment: Also - you are using a `file://` protocol in the href, but the path in the error message appears to be a HTTP path.  You con't need `file://` if the path points to a http location.

Comment: I tried these. This Workbook makes sense.

Comment: The removing of file however, makes it open. But it opens in Chrome, and I am logged on in Explorer. Is there are way to configure it to open in Explorer? When it opens in Chrome it seeks "permissions"

Comment: Likely whatever you have set as your default browser is what it will try to use to open the file.  There's no way in HTML to specify what browser to use.

Comment: Hello, I changed the Path to open from Explorer. This did not resolve the issue. So now I am back to my original path. I created a macro that would Close Excel completely using CMC and reopen it thinking that would refresh the email. But no luck. My current problem is. I Save as the template as a generic name then hit a button that starts a macro to send the link..

Comment: The only issue is I need to close the program and reopen it before emailing the link or else the email recipient cannot open the link. they receive the error message. I know you had mentioned to remove the file:// however, when I reopen the workbook and e-mail it file:// still allows the recipient to open it

Comment: I'll have a look once I can view the screenshots and code in the same window (I have made a suggested edit that is pending) as I'm on the SO app

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help you with your current issue (closing and reopening your file before sending). I've removed the the two lines of your code where you set the Outlook objects to Nothing. To reopen the current file you can use the `OnTime` function like so:

```
Sub Email_created_Workbook()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim Mess As Object, Recip
    Recip = [Sheet1!B28].Value & "; " & [Sheet1!B27].Value
    Dim strbody As String

    If ActiveWorkbook.Path <> "" Then
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        strbody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
              "Hello,<br><br>" & _
              "There is a New PO awaiting your approval :<br><B>" & _
              ActiveWorkbook.Name & "</B> is created.<br>" & _
               "Click on this link to open the file : " & _
              "<A HREF=""file://" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & _
              """>Link to Workbook</A>" & _
              "<br><br>Regards," & _
              "<br><br>Automated Approval System</font>"

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = Recip
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = ActiveWorkbook.Name
            .HTMLBody = strbody
            .Display   'or use .Send
         End With
         Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "SendEmail" 
        ThisWorkbook.Close True 'True= yes, save changes 
    Else
        MsgBox "The ActiveWorkbook does not have a path, Save the file first."
     End If
End Sub

Sub SendEmail() 
    Dim OutApp As Object: Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") 'Grab current instance of Outlook since we already opened the instance prior to restarting Excel
    Dim oInspector As OutApp.Inspector: Set oInspector = OutApp.ActiveInspector
    Dim NewMail As OutApp.MailItem: Set NewMail = oInspector.CurrentItem 'Grab currently open New/Compose Mail window
    NewMail.Send 'Send Email
End Sub
```

Let me know if this helps resolve your issue.